# how to get large scale sparse matrices in matlab, such as 10M*10M

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

How to get a sparse matrix of size 10M*10M in matlab which is normally distributed random matrix or uniformly distributed random matrix. When I do it below, I got error.

```
n = 10000000;   
a = sprandn(n,n,0.1);
fid = fopen('e:/matlab/matrix/normal_1M01.mtx','w');
len = nnz(a);
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','% by taoyuan');
fprintf(fid,'%d %d %d\n',n,n,len);
[m,k,s]=find(a);
for j = 1:len
    fprintf(fid,'%d %d %f\n',m(j),k(j),s(j));
end
fclose(fid);
```

The error is below:

```
??? Error using ==> rand
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

Error in ==> sprandn at 39
   i = fix( rand(nnzwanted, 1) * m ) + 1;

Error in ==> generate at 3
a = sprandn(n,n,0.1);
```

By the way,how to get a sparse matrix which is power-law distributed random matrix, the size is 10M*10M either.

Comment: Each element in a sparse matrix takes up 16 bytes so your matrix requires around `10^7*10^7*0.1*16` bytes which is around 145 Terabytes. I don't think you have that much RAM installed on your computer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to generate nonzeros for one in every 10 elements.

Try `10M * 10M * 0.1`, and think about whether it is reasonable that you have hit the programs limits.

If you have 0.1 as chance it is actually not very sparse. Either reduce the probability (a lot) or work in small batches.

Comment: you are right, it work using "sprandn(n,n,0.0000001)",Thanks!

Comment: how to get a sparse matrix which is power-law distributed random matrix?